# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout can't use the same sections as UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I'm building a view controller with a collection view, using the (kinda) new diffable datasource and composable collectionview layout. I made my own Section and Row enums, can react to changes in my model (an array of photos), which triggers the `applySnapshot` and everything works.

But.. in my `createLayout` function I only have a section index to work with?? This seems very weird to me, why don't these two technologies work better together? One works with `SectionIdentifierType` and `ItemIdentifierType` (great!) and the other is still index based? Ugh.

What I want to be able to do is something like this: all cells within the `Section.header` section need to be full screen width, with an automatic height. Every cell in the `Section.photos` section will get a fixed size. And there can be other sections with different cell sizes too, and some sections can be optional. So an index-based system is really crap to work with, can't hardcode that section 0 is the header and section 1 is photos: the order can change, things might be optional, etc.

What is a better wat to deal with this? I can of course store an array `[Section]` on the view controller, use the section index to get the `Section` case that way, but is there no built-in way to get the section identifier for the index?  It seems like such a logical thing since these 2 technologies were released at the same time.

```swift
class PhotosViewController: UIViewController {
  enum Section: Equatable, Hashable {
    case header
    case photos
  }

  enum Row: Equatable, Hashable {
    case header
    case photo(Photo)
  }

  private lazy var dataSource = makeDataSource()
  var photos: AnyPublisher<[Photo], Never>!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createLayout()

    photos
      .sink(receiveValue: applySnapshot)
      .store(in: &subscriptions)
  }

  private func makeDataSource() -> UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Row> {
    return UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource(collectionView: collectionView) { (collectionView, indexPath, item) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
      switch item {
        case .header:
          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: ProfileHeaderCollectionViewCell.self)
          return cell

        case .photo(let photo):
          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: PhotoCollectionViewCell.self)
          cell.configure(photo: photo)
          return cell
      }
    }
  }

  private func applySnapshot(photos: [Photo]) {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Row>()

    let headerSection = Section.header
    snapshot.appendSections([headerSection])
    snapshot.appendItems([.header], toSection: headerSection)

    let items = photos.map { Row.photo($0) }
    let photosSection = Section.photos
    snapshot.appendSections([photosSection])
    snapshot.appendItems(items, toSection: photosSection)

    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
  }

  private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [unowned self] sectionIndex, _ in
      // I have to work with a sectionIndex instead of a Section case?
    }

    return layout
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of the section identifiers in a separate array, luckily you can just use `dataSource.snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[sectionIndex]`.